# How to add BitmapFont to SelectBox or TextField?

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, scene2d, bitmap-fonts

I follow this link  [InternationalFontsTest.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/extensions/InternationalFontsTest.java)  and I want to use  `Bitmapfont koreanFont` add to Item SelectBox (Scene2d.ui). 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Same as you set it up any style:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { 
  default-font: { file: default.fnt } 
  korean-font: { file:koreanfont.fnt }
  },

com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox$SelectBoxStyle: {
    default: {
        font: default-font, fontColor: white, background: default-select,
        scrollStyle: default,
        listStyle: { font: default-font, selection: default-select-selection }
    }
    korean: {
        font: korean-font, fontColor: white, background: default-select,
        scrollStyle: default,
        listStyle: { font: korean-font, selection: default-select-selection }
    }
},

com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle: {
    default: { selection: selection, background: textfield, font: default-font, fontColor: white, cursor: cursor }
    korean: { selection: selection, background: textfield, font: korean-font, fontColor: white, cursor: cursor }
},
}
```

Not sure how you would create the actual bitmap itself, I don't think hiero can do that but I could be wrong.